# Refreshing fragments in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity, android-adapter

I have a fragment activity with a ViewPager in it, and this fragment activity should send data to the fragments inside of the pager(so the fragments can display the search results). **So my issue is that when I swipe to a fragment it doesnt refresh - I need to swipe few more times between the fragments so they show the new data. Can some tell me what is the propper approach to do this?**

Here is my code:

```
//first i init the widgets
private void initWidgets() {
        bundle = new Bundle();
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.search_progressBar);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.search_viewpager);
        titleStrip = (PagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.search_titlestrip);
        myFragmentPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(myFragmentPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1001);
        titleStrip.setDrawFullUnderline(true);
    }

//then after writing some text in the search i call this function//
private void search(String keyWord) {

        try {
            bundle.putString(IntentConstants.KEYWORD, searchEt.getText().toString());
            myFragmentPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
/*and then the bundle is passed to the fragments - this is in a subclass of the fragmentActivity*/
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position % PAGE_TITLES.length) {
//                community
                case 0:
                    CommunitySearchFragment f = new CommunitySearchFragment();
                    f.setArguments(bundle);
                    return f;
                //My Clipbords Clipboardadater  FragmentSearchMyClipboards
                case 1:


                    FragmentSearchMyClipboards fragment = new FragmentSearchMyClipboards();
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    return fragment;

//                My clips
                case 2:
                    MyClipsFragment f2 = new MyClipsFragment();
                    f2.setArguments(bundle);
                    return f2;
//                members
                case 3:
                    MembersFragment f3 = new MembersFragment();
                    f3.setArguments(bundle);
                    return f3;
            }

            return null;
        }


        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return PAGE_TITLES[position % PAGE_TITLES.length];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5000;
        }
    }
```

and here is one of my fragments as a reference to what i do:

```
public class MyClipsFragment extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<ClipsVO> clipsArray;
    private View mView;
    private ListView list;

    private MyClipboardSearchAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<ClipsVO> rClipsArray;

    private ProgressBar progress;

    @Override
    public void onAPIResponse(ResultVO result) {
        super.onAPIResponse(result);
        if (result.getApiMethod().equals(ClipixServer.APIMETHOD_SEARCHCLIP)) {
            clipsArray = (ArrayList<ClipsVO>) result.getData();
            int userId = Integer.parseInt(UserProfile.getinstance().getUserData().getUserId());

            if (clipsArray.size() > 0) {
                ArrayList<ClipsVO> rClipsArray = new ArrayList<ClipsVO>();
                for (int i = 0; i < clipsArray.size(); i++) {
                    ClipsVO clip = clipsArray.get(i);
                    if (clip.getOwnerUserId().equals(userId + "")) {
                        if (rClipsArray.size() == 0) {
                            //Add header for the Current User's clips in the result
                            ClipsVO headerClip = new ClipsVO();
                            headerClip.setHeader(true);
                            headerClip.setDescription(getLocalizationString("lblCommunityMyClips"));
                            rClipsArray.add(headerClip);
                        }
                        rClipsArray.add(clipsArray.remove(i));
                        i--;
                    }
                }
                if (clipsArray.size() > 0) {
                    //Add header for the other Clipboards in the result
                    ClipsVO headerClip = new ClipsVO();
                    headerClip.setHeader(true);
                    headerClip.setDescription(getLocalizationString("lblClips"));
                    rClipsArray.add(headerClip);
                    rClipsArray.addAll(clipsArray);
                }
            }
            this.rClipsArray = clipsArray;
            if (getActivity() != null)
                setupData();
        }
    }

    private void setupData() {
        adapter = new MyClipboardSearchAdapter(getActivity(), rClipsArray);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        TextView emptyTxt = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.empty);
        emptyTxt.setText(getLocalizationString("txtPeopleSearchNoResult"));
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        emptyTxt.setTextSize(14);
        list.setEmptyView(emptyTxt);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                Object itemObject = rClipsArray.get(position);
                ArrayList<ClipsVO> clipsList = new ArrayList<ClipsVO>();
                ClipsVO clipVO = (ClipsVO) itemObject;
                clipsList.add(clipVO);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ClipsListDetailActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra(IntentConstants.CLIP_DATA, clipVO);
                intent.putExtra(IntentConstants.CLIP_ID, clipVO.getClipId());
                intent.putExtra(IntentConstants.IS_USERCLIPS, false);
                UserProfile.getinstance().setClipsList(clipsList);
                intent.putExtra(IntentConstants.CLIP_INDEX_POSITION, 0);
                intent.putExtra(IntentConstants.CLIPBOARD_INDEX_POSITION, 0);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle
            savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_layout, container, false);
        list = (ListView) mView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_list_layout_list);
        progress = (ProgressBar) mView.findViewById(R.id.frag_progress);
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        rClipsArray = new ArrayList<ClipsVO>();
        if (getArguments().getString(IntentConstants.KEYWORD) != null) {

            //my clips
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            setUserData(params);
            params.put(ClipixServer.FEEDPARAMS_KEYWORD, getArguments().getString(IntentConstants.KEYWORD));
            params.put(ClipixServer.FEEDPARAMS_RESULTCOUNT, "100");
            placeRequest(ClipixServer.APIMETHOD_SEARCHCLIP, Json.METHODNAME_PARSECLIPS, params);

        } else {
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return mView;
    }
}
```

Comment: after you sending data, commit fragment again.

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki yes im sending the data, the fragment gets it but i dont know what is not refreshing right away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1:**

ViewPager loads the fragment by default 1 in the both the sides. so, it can have 3 fragments already loaded in the adapter.

try using the method below

**public void setOffscreenPageLimit (int limit)**

as

**viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);**

this will allow to load the fragments always dynamically.

**Method 2:**

On load of fragment [onAttachActivity] you can refresh the view [set the view contents]